# primeNG confirm dialog message show as html

Tags: angular, primeng, confirmation

I need to show confirm dialog message as html, this is how looks my dialog in component:

```
this.confirmationService.confirm({
        header: "Change user status",
        message: "Do you want to change user status to <strong>" + status + "</strong >?",
        accept: () => {
            //
        }
    });
```

and this is how it looks like on a page:

[image]

I tried to do this two ways but without success

```
<p-confirmDialog width="500" appendTo="body">
<template pTemplate="body">
    <span class="ui-confirmdialog-message">{{message}}</span>
</template>
```

```
<p-confirmDialog width="500" [innerHTML]="message"></p-confirmDialog>
```

Comment: Check this https://plnkr.co/edit/uyLs4OfiPnr3z5kImx0e?p=preview

Comment: Your plunker works, but if I change the message to, e.g., `'Do you want to change user status to <p style="font-size:larger">' + status + '</p>?'` it does not anymore. Ideas?

Answer (score 4):

so this is kind of old, but for the future- the solution is to change the quote type of `message`.

so, change

```
 message: "Do you want to change user status to <strong>" + status + "</strong >?",
```

to

```
 message: `Do you want to change user status to <strong>" + status + "</strong >?`,
```

Answer (score 1):

PrimeNG ConfirmDialog's message element class is ui-confirmdialog-message

Set up a property (e.g: message) in your ts file

```
public message: string;
        
this.confirmationService.confirm({
     header: "Change user status",
     message: this.message,
     accept: () => {
                //
     }
});

this.message = document.getElementsByClassName('ui-confirmdialog-message')[0].innerHTML = "Do you want to change user status to <span id='someOtherId'>" + status + "</span >?"
```

Then in your root styles.css, add this:

```
.ui-confirmdialog-message span#someOtherId { color: yourColor};
```

You can console.log "document.getElementsByClassName('ui-confirmdialog-message')" first to see what's in it. I got an array and the [0] element contains my initial ConfirmDialog message.

There might be a better way but I just happened to tackle this after seeing your question and it worked for me.[Check this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw2Le.png)