# Set PrimeNG confirm message from template

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using a `ConfirmDialog` component from PrimeNg Collection. I can set my message as this:

```
this.confirmationService.confirm({
      message: 'my message',
    });
```

It works but the problem is that it gets messy if I need a big set of tags with other components in there. I want to write my message in an HTML template alongside `p-confirmDialog` tag with Angular's directives and components embedded right into it.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45789799/8468804 Maybe implement something like my answer in this post as a work-around. Mind you but if you want to achieve a template for a variable/property is going to be messy either way.

Comment: I don't want hacks and workarounds. If Angular is so great everything should be possible to do in a right way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach and I think this is a more appropriate way to do it.

`HTML`

```
<p-confirmDialog appendTo="body">
<ng-template pTemplate="body">
    <span class="ui-confirmdialog-message">{{message}}</span>"
</ng-template>
```

`TS`

```
    ...
constructor(private confirmationService: ConfirmationService) {}

private message = `Do you want to change your status to <span style="color:red">inactive</span>` //your template html;
...
this.confirmationService.confirm({
  header: "Some header",
  message: this.message,
  accept: () => {
    //Do something
  }
});
```

You can always have a dedicated Service to call `ConfirmationService` and pass in the `message` as you wish.